# What is the date time format for msdb.dbo.agent_datetime scalar value function?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Looking at msdb.dbo.agent_datetime scalar value function.  What date / time format is this expressed in, UTC?  Same question for msdb.dbo.sysjobs columns : run_date, run_time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you asking about the format or the value?

By "value" I mean if it is in UTC or the local datetime value.

The function doesn't have a stored value, it work with what you pass into it and returns a datetime value based on that. I.e., there's no UTC relevance for this.

The columns, for instance in sysjobhistory, are *not* in UTC. They are in the local timezone (for your SQL Server instance).

As for the format:

The tables uses a pair of int columns - one for date and one for time. So the int 20191223 means 2019-12-23 (I'm using ISO 8609 format when communicating datetime values).

The function accepts two parameters, both int. One for the date and one for the time, as described above. It returns a datetime value (which has no format - it is just a value).

In case you wonder how I know it returns a datetime and not datetime2(3): You can investigate a value by casting it to sql_variant and then investigate properties of that value using the SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY function:

```
DECLARE @a sql_variant
SET @a = dbo.agent_datetime(20201023,154500)
SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@a, 'BaseType')
```

Above returns:

```
datetime
```